# Why does the prompt differ for `tcsh` depending on whether it's invoked as `tcsh` or `csh`

Tags: tcsh

I installed the `tcsh` package on Ubuntu 15.10 and the prompt differs depending on how I invoke `tcsh`.

First off, on Ubuntu 15.10, `tcsh` and `csh` really are the same executable:

```
$ cmp /bin/tcsh /bin/csh && echo 'same' || echo 'different'
same

$ /bin/tcsh
hostname:/tmp>

$ /bin/tcsh -f
>
```

Whereas with `/bin/csh` it ends with a percent sign

```
$ /bin/csh
hostname:/tmp%

$ /bin/csh -f
%
```

I haven't set a `.cshrc` or a `.tcshrc` file. Is `tcsh` inspecting the first element of argv to determine what to use as the final character of the prompt?

The `/etc/csh.cshrc` file does contain logic for changing the prompt if the program is invoked as `tcsh`, but it is not clear why setting the prompt in this way would change the last character from `>` to `%`. This file is also ignored if the `-f` flag is provided.

```
# /etc/csh.cshrc: system-wide .cshrc file for csh(1) and tcsh(1)

if ($?tcsh && $?prompt) then

    bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line # Home
    bindkey "\e[7~" beginning-of-line # Home rxvt
    bindkey "\e[2~" overwrite-mode    # Ins
    bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char       # Delete
    bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line       # End
    bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line       # End rxvt

    set autoexpand
    set autolist
    set prompt = "%U%m%u:%B%~%b%# "
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see it in the manpage, but the source code checks if the program is invoked as `tcsh` or not.  If it *is*, the code sets the prompt as noted in the question:

```
HIST = '!';
HISTSUB = '^';
PRCH = tcsh ? '>' : '%';    /* to replace %# in $prompt for normal users */
PRCHROOT = '#';             /* likewise for root */
word_chars = STR_WORD_CHARS;
bslash_quote = 0;           /* PWP: do tcsh-style backslash quoting? */
```

The program logic is fairly easy to read:

```
    {
        char *t;

        t = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
#ifdef WINNT_NATIVE
        {
            char *s = strrchr(argv[0], '\\');
            if (s)
                t = s;
        }
#endif /* WINNT_NATIVE */
        t = t ? t + 1 : argv[0];
        if (*t == '-') t++;
        progname = strsave((t && *t) ? t : tcshstr);    /* never want a null */
        tcsh = strncmp(progname, tcshstr, sizeof(tcshstr) - 1) == 0;
    }
```

and

```
static const char tcshstr[] = "tcsh";
```

So it would not pass the test if it were named `tcsh10`, for instance.